# Converting from AoS to SoA - Write performance and Optimal packing

Tags: arrays, struct, cuda

I am currently thinking about converting the data storage used in my CUDA kernels from Array of Structs (AoS) to Struct of Arrays (SoA).

I have a struct `Element`:

```
struct Element
{
    float3 origin;
    float3 direction;
    uint8_t count1;
    uint8_t count2;
    unsigned int index;
    float distance;
    uint16_t instanceId;
    uint64_t hash;
};
```

These structs are written in `kernel1` each as a whole into an array residing in global memory and then subsets of the entries are used in multiple subsequent kernels.

I could now convert this to the following structure:

```
struct ElementSoA
{
    float3 origin[N];
    float3 direction[N];
    uint8_t count1[N];
    uint8_t count2[N];
    unsigned int index[N];
    float distance[N];
    uint16_t instanceId[N];
    uint64_t hash[N];
};
```

**Questions:**

1) Is the write performance affected if I have 8 separate, "small" writes in `kernel1` instead of 1 "big" write?

2) Would it make sense to "pack" parts of the entries within `ElementSoA`, e.g. combining `count1` and `count2` into a

```
  struct uint8_2
  {
       uint8_t count1;
       uint8_t count2;
  };
```

3) If "packing" is useful, is there a way to **calculate** the optimal structure of `ElementSoA`?
Suppose I have a list of the per-kernel read accesses like this:

- `kernel2`: `origin`, `direction`, `hash`
- `kernel3`: `count1`, `count2`, `distance`, `hash`
- ...

The reason I ask for a calculation of the optimal solution is that I have multiple structs and they contain even more entries than `Element`, so there is a huge number of combinations which I need to implement and test.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly  I updated my question. Given the huge number of combinations, maybe there is a way to limit the necessary tests ...

Comment: It's still not clear what the access pattern is. Does thread `i` access element `i` and only element `i`? From the context I'd assume so, but that would be nice to make explicit.

Comment: @Jez yes,  for most of the kernels only one element per thread is accessed. But maybe I have to build some automated combination building and testing to find the global optimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that thread `i` accesses element `i` and only element `i`. From the context this seems to be the case.

> Is the write performance affected if I have 8 separate, "small" writes
>   in kernel1 instead of 1 "big" write?

**Yes**. It should be faster. The "big" write will be split into multiple small writes by the compiler, each of which will be strided. The memory subsystem works much better when access pattern is unstrided.

It's worth pointing out here that the `float3` types you're using will also work like this, and will be split into three 32-bit transactions with a stride. There's no reason you can't convert these from AoS to SoA as well though.

> Would it make sense to "pack" parts of the entries within `ElementSoA`?

**Yes**. Larger aligned power-of-two types (on current hardware, up to 128 bits) allow the hardware to load and store more efficiently. The difference isn't huge, but if it's easy to do, it's often worth it.

> If "packing" is useful, is there a way to **calculate** the optimal
>   structure of `ElementSoA`?

**There is no way to calculate this**. One problem is that kernels have different characteristics. It maybe be that one is strongly bandwidth bound, so using efficient loads will help. Another may be compute bound, so more efficient loads won't help much.

Comment: about `float3`: since this is a builtin type, isn't this somewhat more optimized than a plain `float[3]` array?

Comment: No, it's not. When it comes down to it each float3 is just a 12-byte area of memory. To get 12 unpadded bytes directly from memory to registers there's no real other way than strided access as the transaction sizes available are a powers of two.